# How to set a char 'a' to a char pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I'm trying to figure out how to use pointers.

I'm confused on how to insert an individual char to the char *line2[80]

Is this even possible to do this without referencing the memory location of another pointer?

My thought process is that at *line2[0] = 'a' the character 'a' will be at index 0 of the array.

How is this different from line[0] = 'a'

```
#include <stdio.h>

void returnValue(void);

int main(void){
    returnValue();

}


void returnValue(){
    char line[80];
    line[0] = 'a';
    line[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s",line);

    char* line2[80];
    *line2[0] = 'a';
    *line2[1] = '\0';
     printf("%s",*line2); //program crashes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate

```
char* line2[80];
```

You are allocating an **array of 80 character pointers**.

When you use

```
*line2[0] = 'a';
```

You are referencing undefined behaviour. This is because you are allocating the pointer `line2[0]`, but the pointer is not initialized and may not be pointing to any valid location in memory.

You need to initialize the pointer to some valid location in memory for this to work. The typical way to do this would be to use `malloc`

```
line2[0] = malloc(10); // Here 10 is the maximum size of the string you want to store
*line2[0] = 'a';
*(line2[0]+1) = '\0';
printf("%s",*line2);
```

What you are doing in the above program is allocating a 2D array of C strings. `line2[0]` is the 1st string. Likewise, you can have 79 more strings allocated.

Comment: One thing to note as well. When using malloc you must add the header file #include <stdlib.h>. Malloc is short for memory allocation I believe. Just wanted to add that for future reference. Thank you. +1

Comment: Wouldn't it still be a 1d array? Wouldn't a 2d array be char* line2[80][80]? Or is this something unique to pointers?

Comment: @pewpew That would be a 2D array of char pointers, for a 2D char array use `char line2[80][80]`

Comment: you could use `line2[0][1]`, which is maybe better readable than `*(line2[0]+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

you must have already read, a pointer is a special variable in `c` which stores address of another variable of same `datatype`.

for eg:-

```
char a_character_var = 'M'; 
char * a_character_pointer = &a_character_var; //here `*` signifies `a_character_pointer` is a `pointer` to `char datatype` i.e. it can store an address of a `char`acter variable
```

likewise in your example

`char* line2[80];` is an array of `80` `char` pointer

usage

```
line2[0] = &line[0];
```

and you may access it by writing `*line2[0]` which will yield `a` as output

Comment: How would you set the a_character_pointer to a_character_var if they are both arrays? char *  a_character_pointer[0] = a_character_var[0]? What if the arrays are larger?

Comment: you just have to initialize the `BaseAddress` of the variable you want (be it a plain `variable` or an `array`) to the `pointer` and to `dereference` it, simply by increase the `pointer` location and reading it's value